# Next.js Deployment with Docker : Error no such file or directory

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm seeking help with a deployment issue involving a Next.js project using Docker. The problem arises when I execute the command docker-compose up --build with my environment variable set to 'production'. At this point, I encounter an error. Can anyone provide guidance on resolving this issue?

My error :
`[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'] { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '/app/.next/BUILD_ID' }`

Here is my Dockerfile and docker-compose :

```
FROM node:20-alpine as base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Copie des fichiers de dépendances et installation des dépendances
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Génération du client Prisma (si nécessaire)
RUN npx prisma generate



# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Arguments pour l'environnement et la base de données
ARG NODE_ENV

# Définir les variables d'environnement
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

# Copiez les fichiers nécessaires depuis l'étape builder
COPY --from=builder /app/ ./

# Construction de l'application Next.js seulement pour la production
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ]; then \
        yarn build; \
    fi

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

EXPOSE 3000

# Définir la commande par défaut en fonction de l'environnement
CMD if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ]; then \
        yarn start; \
    else \
        yarn dev; \
    fi
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
        DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: >
      sh -c "npx prisma db push &&
             if [ \"$NODE_ENV\" = 'production' ]; then
               yarn start;
             else
               yarn dev;
             fi"
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

What steps have you already attempted in resolving this issue, and what were your expected results? Understanding what you have tried so far will help in diagnosing the problem more effectively.